# In Postman GET working fine but POST method keeps on sending request. Using Mongoose, Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, express, mongoose, postman

**PROBLEM**: When I am making the POST request in postman, the postman keeps on sending requests and I do not get any response.

I went through other answers about postman hanging when POST request is made, but could not find a solution to my problem.

**GET REQUEST WORKING FINE**

[image: Get request working fine]

Following is the request that I made

```
{
"title": "This is title",
"description":"This is my first RestfulAPI"
}
```

[image: POSTMAN keeps on sending request]

I have 3 files Post.js, posts.js, app.js

**Post.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Creating a schema
const PostSchema= mongoose.Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
})
module.exports=mongoose.model('Posts',PostSchema);
```

**posts.js**

```
const express= require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const Post= require('../models/Post');
router.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('We are on posts');
});

router.get('/specific',(req,res) => {
res.send('Specific posts');
});

router.post('/',async (req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body);
const post= new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description
});

try{
const savedPost = await post.save();
res.json(savedPost).status(3000).end();
}catch(err){
    res.json({message: err}).status(3000).end();
    console.log('Something is wrong');
}
});

module.exports= router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const app= express();
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');
app.use('/posts',postsRoute);

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
res.send('We are on home');
});


mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION,{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true },() => 
console.log('connected to DB!')
);
app.listen(3000);
```

My console after sending POST request
[image]

Comment: `res.json(savedPost).status(3000).end();` ? wouldn't that be `res.status(3000).json(savedPost)`

Comment: between 3000 is not a valid status code... you should use 200 or 2.X.X status for an ok response.

Comment: @anees I removed .status().

Answer (score 0):

You would not need `.end()` after calling `res.json()`, as you probably want to send the `savedPost` back to the client.

The express documentation mentions [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) that

> [res.end()] is used to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json().

You also need to send back the proper HTTP code that ranges from 1xx to 5xx, when working with HTTP. You can read more about them [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Your response should probably look like

```
res.status(200).json(savedPost);
```